# Customize divider when collapsing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When my navbar is collapsed the divider is big. How can I customize it or edit it? Please help me, I'm new to css and html also to bootstrap. Thanks in advance. Im using bootstrap.

[image]

Here's my code.

```
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav-collapse">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Students</a></li>
              <li class="nav-divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Faculty</a></li>
              <li class="nav-divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
              <li class="nav-divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
              <li class="nav-divider"></li>

            </ul>

               <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
                    <!-- Modal -->
                        <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <!-- Modal content-->
                             <div class="modal-content">
                                 <div class="modal-header">
                                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                     <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="modal-body">
                                    <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                 </div>
                             </div>
                            </div>
                       </div>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
</nav>
```

here is my css code.

```
#fot { 
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
}
.navbar-default {
    background-color:rgb(193,57,45);
}
.navbar .nav > li > a {
    color:#ffe6e6;
}
.navbar .nav > li > a:hover {
    color:#000000;
}
.navbar .nav .active > a{
    background-color:rgb(193,57,45);
    color:#000000;
}
.navbar .nav .active > a:hover{
    background:none;
    color:#fff;
}
.nav .nav-divider{
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    border-right: 1px solid #a92419;
    border-left: 1px solid #c1392d;
}
.nav .nav-divider {
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    border-right: 1px solid #a92419;
    border-left: 1px solid #c1392d;
}
```

Comment: seems like you did forget to post the css code?

Comment: sorry sir. i edit it alrleady.

Comment: can you help me :(

Comment: I can't I don't even see any divider when it collapses [**link**](https://i.gyazo.com/0455b81b99a92ed4ef2658987ef6ac30.png)

Comment: i post the picture sir. take a look at that white gray.

Comment: this is a divider! I thought it was an input box; sorry.

Comment: how can i customize it?

Comment: you must to change `.nav .nav-divider { height: 50px; margin: 0 10px;` on your stylesheet (replace with smaller values).

Comment: if i change it the divider in navbar when not collapsing will become smaller too. i tried. but when collapsing its working its smaller too but the nav when not collapsing is small too. :3

Comment: no, just change the `.nav .nav-divider` inside the @media queries for small devices;

Comment: can you post a sample code?

Comment: i don't know that media thing lol. im newbie

Comment: Example if you use `.nav bar{background: red} @media(max-width: 768px){.nav bar{background: blue}}` the navbar will become red, except in small devices (smaller than 768px width), where it will be blue.

Comment: Thanks it worked. Do u know how to customize the color of the button of collapsing button?

Comment: This kind of parallel "chat" help goes against the stackoverflow guidelines so I can't go too further with it. My advice is: right click on the element that you want (collapsing button) and then click on "inspect" so the browser's console will show up with all info about that object, css, errors (if any) and etc;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The border at the bottom of the navbar seems to be coloured by the following CSS rule in bootstrap:

```css
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse, .navbar-default .navbar-form {
    border-color: #e7e7e7; 
}
```

You could override this rule to change it's width or color.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Media Query** to adjust your CSS styling in various viewports. This method comes in handy with pretty much everything when constructing your layout in Bootstrap.

Like following:

```
@media (max-width: 768px)
{
   .navbar-default {
      background-color: #fff;
      color: #000;
      padding: 5px;
   }
}
```

Place this to the bottom of your CSS and you can adjust every style of your navbar. In `@media` you simply tell the CSS when to apply the styles you've put inside that media query. While the value is `max-width: 768px`, it will only take effect when your screen's viewport / size is below that value. If you'd change it to `min-width` instead, it would style the `.navbar-default` in everywhere else, but reset to default in what we call mobile-view.